# How to extract specific path from string using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

i have string name Path:

```
Path = 's3://ihsm-dl-automotive-dev/auto_target_marketing_data/Testing-sandbox/PP_PROCESS_TESTING_DEEPAK/Buick_Encore_studyfile'
```

i want to create two string and store in two different variables as given below;

```
bucket = 'ihsm-dl-automotive-dev'
path_new = 'auto_target_marketing_data/Testing-sandbox/PP_PROCESS_TESTING_DEEPAK/Buick_Encore_studyfile'
```

i have tried few option like split by delimiter  like **Path.split('/')** but it gives me in list form.

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: find '//' first to get the start offset of bucket, then find the first '/' to get the end offset of bucket, which is also the start offset of the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a constant bucket name, why not split with that name and use that to split and then slice the string with :

```
Path.split(bucket)[1][1:]
```

OR

If you dont have a constant bucket string, use:

```
a=Path.split("/")
bucket,path=a[2],"/".join(a[3:])
```

This will give you a list, but you can join them using `join`